# How do I return a None in scala?

Tags: scala

I've been learning Scala recently and one of the things I've seen most is talk about how you shouldn't use null but instead use None. I've had to resort to using null some times because I don't understand how None works exactly.

My biggest problem is when I have methods which return an object say:

```
def func: SomeObjType = {
if(something)
    new SomeObjType
else
    null or None
```

If I return null, it works perfectly well but whenever I try to return None it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
def func : Option[SomeObjType] = {
  if (cond)
    Some(new SomeObjType)
  else 
    None
}
```

Comment: But this changes my return type. Is there any way to do this just like in java, without changing my return type?

Comment: @JesusAdoboLuzon the whole point of Option is to return different type, this way caller **know** that there is some risk of absent value, moreover it cannot perform *direct unsafe* operations on result. If you don't need this and restricted with some signature, use plain old null.

Comment: Guess my problem is trying to do it the Java way. Thanks for the responses! :D

Comment: Suggest putting this all one line and not using unnecessary curly braces.

Answer (score -3):

**None**, as you can see in the scaladocs [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.None%24), is an extension of Option.  It only checks out if your return type is expected to be an Option.

You can alter your code as Marth suggests, but in practice, **Option** makes for rather ugly code if it is used constantly.

If you are dealing with Lists, returning a **Nil** would be quite suitable.

I personally just return **Nothing**, just because it sounds cool, and because its autoinheritence of every class (including **SomeObjType**) makes it simple to deal with.

The following article is a very useful piece about these absentee-types in Scala:

[A Post About Nothing](http://oldfashionedsoftware.com/2008/08/20/a-post-about-nothing/), by Matt Malone

And really, with all these alternatives, there's little appeal for a lower-case *null*.  It even pales in the face of the aesthetically-pleasing **Null**.  Quirks aside, *null* and **Null** can be used more or less interchangeably.

Comment: The `Option` type (with `Some` and `None`) is specifically made to indicate values that can optionally be empty. So, why not use it? You can't return a `Nothing` from a method that has return type `SomeObjType`, because there are no instances of the type `Nothing`. Also, `Null` and `null` are not really interchangeable. `Null` is a *type* and `null` is a *value* (of type `Null`).